# Why isn't the shine/gloss showing on the character when I render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I don't know why the character is appearing like it has no textures. I made it so it should have gloss/ shine to it.

[image: Final Render]

[image: What the shader stuff is]

[image: Viewport]

Comment: Did you add lights or hdri in your scene while rendering?

Comment: There's a single spotlight with 200 power shining at the character. it's not even showing the cloud texture on it so I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you share the blend file? Just upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and share the link in gives.

Comment: The file is too big.

Comment: Hmm...Then you can use google drive or dropbox and enable link sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uaL3ay43eaz0xCsw2g4l2fCy5zEJv2xV/view?usp=sharing does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just what I expected,

**There are no lights.**
You are rendering a closed space with no lights. Of course, it's not gonna be visible in the render.

As you can see in the image below adding just four point lights set to about 400watts power helped so much. There is nothing wrong with your material you just don't have any lights for the material to reflect.

Also, the table cloths and some other things are pink because you didn't pack the image textures in the blend file you shared.
[image]

Comment: Hmm. I was confused because I thought I had put a spotlight that is parented to the camera. But thank you so much for the help

Comment: It is only because of the spotlight that an outline of your character is visible, without it the whole render would be pitch black. You can see so by increasing and decreasing the strength of the spotlight. Spotlight is helping but it's not enough

Comment: is it still possible to make the image a little dark while still having the shine on the character?

Comment: to be more precise there is a light (the spot) but its strength is too low

Comment: The model alone is 5 meters high. Therefore, the 200W light is too weak to illuminate the whole room. You can try an HDRI background image for the world settings. But for that to work, you need to remove the walls of the room so it's open and the light can shine in from outside.